# Why should I be failing this simple python algorithm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, collision-detection, collision

I have an algorithm that I want to write in python and analyze it. I think I wrote it well, but my output doesn't match what the given output should be.

given algorithm;

```
Input{inStr: a binary string of bytes}
Output{outHash: 32-bit hashcode for the inStr in a series of hex values}
Mask: 0x3FFFFFFF
outHash: 0
for byte in input
intermediate_value = ((byte XOR 0xCC) Left Shift 24) OR
((byte XOR 0x33) Left Shift 16) OR
((byte XOR 0xAA) Left Shift 8) OR
(byte XOR 0x55)
outHash =(outHash AND Mask) + (intermediate_value AND Mask)
return outHash
```

My algorithm version in python is;

```
Input = "Hello world!"
Mask = 0x3FFFFFFF
outHash = 0

for byte in Input:
    intermediate_value = ((ord(byte) ^ 0xCC) << 24) or ((ord(byte) ^ 0x33) << 16) or ((ord(byte) ^ 0xAA) << 8) or (ord(byte) ^ 0x55)
outHash =(outHash & Mask) + (intermediate_value & Mask)

print outHash

# use %x to print result in hex
print '%x'%outHash
```

For input "Hello world!", I should see output as 0x50b027cf, but my output is too different, it looks like;

```
1291845632
4d000000
```

Comment: You are overwriting your _intermediate_value_ on each iteration, essentially using its value for the last _byte_ only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OR must be bitwise OR operator (|).

Comment: @user124627, you are wrong. _1 or 2_ gives 1, _0 or 2_ gives 2. _1|2_ gives 3

Comment: Actually, since all the value fall in different byte offset, adding will work too - at least, the way it's written now